# An array implementation of a queue is more difficult to manage than the array implementation of a stack, True/False

Tags: data-structures

I am trying to understand which would be easier to implement. I understand that a queue is FIFO and a stack is LIFO. Thus if I add elements to an array, it would be simpler to print FIFO rather than LIFO... or am I going about this the wrong way.

Answer (score 1):

More difficult to manage? Yes, but not slower. Buffered queues are implemented as circular buffers (see Java's ArrayDeque) which increases complexity, but insertion and removal even for a deque takes O(1).

The difference goes when the buffer needs to be reallocated. In a queue (or generally speaking, a circular buffer) you might need to shift a lot of elements (at least you are not shifting all elements in every insertion) and in a stack you'll never need to do that.

If you make a circular buffer, then you can have it work as a stack, a queue and a deque.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a bit vague, but I would say that a programmer is about twice as likely to make in important mistake in the implementation of an unbounded array-based queue than he is in the implementation of an unbounded array-based stack.

The queue will also require about 30% more code.

In those ways we could say that a queue is more difficult to manage.